# MixItUp hide elements when change the page

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, mixitup

I used [mixitup](https://github.com/patrickkunka/mixitup). I developed mixitup directive as the following:

```
app.directive('mixitup',function(){
  var linker = function(scope,element,attrs) {
    scope.$watch('entities', function(){
        element.mixItUp();
    });
  };   
  return {
    restrict:'A',
    link: linker,
    scope:{entities:'='}
  }
});
```

My code is similar to this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyakout91/um1a7dz1/).

My issue is that I have many tabs, when I click on one of them, it'll redirect to another page. When I return back to `mixitup` page, all of DOM elements is hidden.

1. What's the wrong in the directive ?
2. How can I make all DOM elements display when I switch among different pages ?

Comment: Create demo that replicates problem. A demo that works doesn't help us much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the error, I missed `$destroy` call back function in the directive.

So the directive must be as the following:

```
app.directive('mixitup',function(){
  var linker = function(scope,element,attrs) {
    scope.$watch('entities', function(){
        element.mixItUp();
    });

    element.on('$destroy', function() {
        element.mixItUp('destroy');
    });
  };   
  return {
    restrict:'A',
    link: linker,
    scope:{entities:'='}
  }
});
```

That's to destroy the element after redirect to another page. Then when I return to the `mixitup` page. I'll re-start the element again.